# REST API - Get details of first matching record

Tags: rest

Suppose I send a GET request to the following endpoint:

`/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/Email/test@email.com`

If there is only one contact with that email, the response I get from the API contains all the fields for that contact. But if there is more than one match, the response looks like this:

```
[
  "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/00Q6F0000144bUxUAI",
  "/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/00Q6F0000144bEFUAY"
]
```

Is there any way to force the initial request to always return the fields from the first contact, ignoring the rest?

Otherwise I need to look into the response, extract the contact ID, and make a second GET request, which I really would love to avoid.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why not run a SOQL using Rest api, you can add LIMIT 1 there?

Comment: As far as I know, I can't do SELECT * FROM Contacts. I'd rather not have to manually build the query. But no other reason, to be honest. If it's the only way to get all the results I need in a single query I might just go that way... Thanks @SantanuHalder!

Comment: You don't have to write the SOQL Query manually, you can use Dynamic SOQL to fetch all fields. Please check this [link](https://corycowgill.blogspot.in/2011/01/building-dynamic-soql-select-all-query.html).